# remove quotes in generated file

Tags: php, fopen

I am using a script to convert a Magento exported CSV file into a tab delimited TXT file. For some reason however several columns are between quotes. Is there a way to fully remove quotes?

My script:

```
    <?php
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("/var/www/html/var/export/export_orders.csv", "r")) && $myfile = fopen("/var/www/html/var/export/export_orders.txt", "w")) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            $row++;
            fputcsv($myfile, $data, "\t");
        }
        fclose($handle);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
    ?>
```

my output (txt):

```
    100009407   "2018-03-07 02:16:39"   processing  PayPal      freeshipping_freeshipping   6007.0000   0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  6007.0000   6007.0000   6007.0000   0   0   34.0000 2004    "customer name" xxxx    "xxxx"  xxxx4@gmail.com "xxxx"                  "address1"  76120   xxxx    "xxxx"  processing  LP012   8855708513503   99.0000 99.0000 2.0000  2.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  198.0000    "Home delivery - Nationwide"    "10:00 "    " 17:00"    "2018-03-08 00:00:00"
```

Why is certain data being quoted? Like I said, I would like to have no quotes at all. Some expert advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Use `implode` if you don't need all this csv functionality.

Comment: Do these values have quotes in the input file?

Comment: No they don't @NigelRen

Comment: Could you elaborate @u_mulder? We had our programmer however he just went AWOL and I just want this to work

Comment: @Dan  change `fputcsv($myfile, $data, "\t");` to `fputcsv($myfile, str_replace('"','',$data), "\t");`

Comment: PHP will quote anything with a `\s` space or the delimiter in it, when using `fputcsv` it's normal.

Comment: Thank you @AlivetoDie, but still adding quotes

Comment: what can I do to fix this @ArtisticPhoenix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though, I don't know why you do all this, because csv-format is widely used, but if you don't want any limitations of this format, you can create a string of a required format with just `implod`ing array values and `fwrite` it to file:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $row++;
    fwrite($myfile, implode("\t", $data) . "\n");
    // or with PHP_EOL as line end
    // fwrite($myfile, implode("\t", $data) . PHP_EOL);
}
fclose($handle);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: seems correct.+1. Now OP have to confirm that worked or not?

Comment: @AlivetoDie though I don't know how this file with mess of tabs and spaces will be parsed further.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix that's why I don't know what OP wants. If he wants values delimited with tabs - this is the solution.

Comment: Yea, I thought it was comma, it should be ok as long as there are no tabs in the data.  Still I wouldn't mess with the format, whatever he needs it for, he should fix that instead of messing this up.

Comment: @NigelRen - no PHP_EOL, is junk ... lol.  the `\n` works fine on windows.

Comment: You cant put empty in for the `enclosed by`  I think you can put in `\0` but don't say I told you that.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will put `"` around anything with a space when using `fputcsv`  it's the normal expected behaviour.

So this

```
"10:00 "
```

Has a space, as does

```
"2018-03-07 02:16:39"
```

And `"customer name"`

etc.

For the most part unless something else is wrong, this should be fine, as PHP can read it fine, Excel will do just fine.

Now if you want to get rid of some of the spaces such as `10:00` then you can use trim and array map

```
 $data = array_map('trim', $data);
```

**UPDATE**

You can use implode or you can put a null byte `"\0"` or `chr(0)` in for the enclosure.  You would think putting `''` empty in there would work but it doesn't. But don't say I told you to do it ... lol ... it's a bit of a hack.

You can test it with this little piece of code

```
$f = fopen('php://temp', "w+");

$a = ["the fox", "jumpled", "over the rox"];

fputcsv($f, $a, "\t", chr(0));

rewind($f);

echo str_replace("\t", '\t', fgets($f));
```

Outputs:

```
the fox\tjumpled\tover the rox
```

Also ignore my use of the dynamic stream wrappers....

Comment: how can I fix this in my current script? I am really no programmer and I just want it to work. Your help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Remove the spaces...  for example `trim("10:00 ")`

Comment: No it won't work - i need this to work over the script

Comment: `over the script` what does that mean.  Messing with the CSV format is a very slippery slope.

Comment: @Dan try the other answer. Add a comment under the answer that it worked or not

Comment: Is there any way this can be applied onto my current script? I understand you're very knowledgeable and my apologies ,@ArtisticPhoenix but I am a business owner and our developer bailed on us leaving me in the plain desert

Comment: All you have to do is add `chr(0)` to this line, `fputcsv($myfile, $data, "\t");` as the last argument, `fputcsv($myfile, $data, "\t", chr(0));`  However you have to understand it's not that it's removing the `"` it just putting a null byte in place of it.  Now as to how this works out later I cant say as I never used it in a production environment.